# Specify hours in mysql date selection

Tags: php, mysql

```
$datef = (date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'])));
```

Out of interest, i'm using this code above to select records from mysql, which bits would i have to change to specify hours aswell not just month, day and year. The column type is TIMESTAMP if that helps,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change:

`"Y-m-d"` to `"Y-m-d h-i-s"`

If looks like your date manipulation is within the PHP, see here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

However- the question is a little ambiguous. If you are trying to take the value of `$datef` and use in your SQL, you may want to do this:

```
$day=$_POST['day'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$hour=12;
$minute=00;
$second=00;

$datef=strtotime($year.":".$month.":".$day." ".$hour.":".$minute.":".$second);
```

Comment: Although- note that if hour values arent available, it wouldnt matter. In the stated code, this seems to be the case (no data for hours is posted).

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work, you will have to modify your mysql query a little, otherwise, you will only fetch the records with the exact time you specified (e.g.: 12:00:00, but not 12:00:01):

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2010-11-01 07:00:00' AND '2010-11-01 07:59:59'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE datefield LIKE '2010-11-01 07%';
```